# Watir-webdriver how to access LAST matching element not first?

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver, browser-automation

On a dynamic web page I don't know the number of matching elements upfront, so I won't know which index # to use.

Does watir-webdriver provide a way to access the LAST matching element, not first as by default?

The HTML in question forms a calendar control

```
<table border="0" class="body-style">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td width="27" align="right"><b>Sun</b></td>
      <td width="27" align="right"><b>Mon</b></td>
      <td width="27" align="right"><b>Tue</b></td>
      <td width="27" align="right"><b>Wed</b></td>
      <td width="27" align="right"><b>Thu</b></td>
      <td width="27" align="right"><b>Fri</b></td>
      <td width="27" align="right"><b>Sat</b></td></tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="right"><p class="end-of-weekday-style">Â&nbsp;1Â&nbsp;</p></td>
      <td align="right"><p class="end-of-weekday-style">Â&nbsp;2Â&nbsp;</p></td>
      <td align="right"><p class="end-of-weekday-style">Â&nbsp;3Â&nbsp;</p></td>
      <td align="right"><p class="end-of-weekday-style">Â&nbsp;4Â&nbsp;</p></td>
      <td align="right"><p class="end-of-weekday-style">Â&nbsp;5Â&nbsp;</p></td>
      <td align="right"><p class="end-of-weekday-style">Â&nbsp;6Â&nbsp;</p></td>
      <td align="right"><p class="end-of-weekday-style">Â&nbsp;7Â&nbsp;</p></td></tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="right"><p class="end-of-weekday-style">Â&nbsp;8Â&nbsp;</p></td>
      <td align="right"><p class="end-of-weekday-style">Â&nbsp;9Â&nbsp;</p></td>
      <td align="right"><p class="end-of-weekday-style">Â&nbsp;10Â&nbsp;</p></td>
      <td align="right"><p class="end-of-weekday-style">Â&nbsp;11Â&nbsp;</p></td>
      <td align="right"><p class="end-of-weekday-style">Â&nbsp;12Â&nbsp;</p></td>
      <td align="right"><a class="current-day-style selected-day-style" onmousemove="window.status=&quot; &quot;" onmouseout="window.status=&quot; &quot;" title="" href="javascript:dateSelected=13;closeCalendar();doOtherFunctions();">Â&nbsp;13Â&nbsp;</a></td>
      <td align="right"><p class="end-of-weekday-style">Â&nbsp;14Â&nbsp;</p></td></tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="right"><p class="end-of-weekday-style">Â&nbsp;15Â&nbsp;</p></td>
      <td align="right"><a class="normal-day-style" onmousemove="window.status=&quot; &quot;" onmouseout="window.status=&quot; &quot;" title="" href="javascript:dateSelected=16;closeCalendar();doOtherFunctions();">Â&nbsp;16Â&nbsp;</a></td>
      <td align="right"><a class="normal-day-style" onmousemove="window.status=&quot; &quot;" onmouseout="window.status=&quot; &quot;" title="" href="javascript:dateSelected=17;closeCalendar();doOtherFunctions();">Â&nbsp;17Â&nbsp;</a></td>
      <td align="right"><a class="normal-day-style" onmousemove="window.status=&quot; &quot;" onmouseout="window.status=&quot; &quot;" title="" href="javascript:dateSelected=18;closeCalendar();doOtherFunctions();">Â&nbsp;18Â&nbsp;</a></td>
      <td align="right"><a class="normal-day-style" onmousemove="window.status=&quot; &quot;" onmouseout="window.status=&quot; &quot;" title="" href="javascript:dateSelected=19;closeCalendar();doOtherFunctions();">Â&nbsp;19Â&nbsp;</a></td>
      <td align="right"><a class="normal-day-style" onmousemove="window.status=&quot; &quot;" onmouseout="window.status=&quot; &quot;" title="" href="javascript:dateSelected=20;closeCalendar();doOtherFunctions();">Â&nbsp;20Â&nbsp;</a></td>
      <td align="right"><p class="end-of-weekday-style">Â&nbsp;21Â&nbsp;</p></td></tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="right"><p class="end-of-weekday-style">Â&nbsp;22Â&nbsp;</p></td>
      <td align="right"><a class="normal-day-style" onmousemove="window.status=&quot; &quot;" onmouseout="window.status=&quot; &quot;" title="" href="javascript:dateSelected=23;closeCalendar();doOtherFunctions();">Â&nbsp;23Â&nbsp;</a></td>
      <td align="right"><a class="normal-day-style" onmousemove="window.status=&quot; &quot;" onmouseout="window.status=&quot; &quot;" title="" href="javascript:dateSelected=24;closeCalendar();doOtherFunctions();">Â&nbsp;24Â&nbsp;</a></td>
      <td align="right"><a class="normal-day-style" onmousemove="window.status=&quot; &quot;" onmouseout="window.status=&quot; &quot;" title="" href="javascript:dateSelected=25;closeCalendar();doOtherFunctions();">Â&nbsp;25Â&nbsp;</a></td>
      <td align="right"><a class="normal-day-style" onmousemove="window.status=&quot; &quot;" onmouseout="window.status=&quot; &quot;" title="" href="javascript:dateSelected=26;closeCalendar();doOtherFunctions();">Â&nbsp;26Â&nbsp;</a></td>
      <td align="right"><a class="normal-day-style" onmousemove="window.status=&quot; &quot;" onmouseout="window.status=&quot; &quot;" title="" href="javascript:dateSelected=27;closeCalendar();doOtherFunctions();">Â&nbsp;27Â&nbsp;</a></td>
      <td align="right"><p class="end-of-weekday-style">Â&nbsp;28Â&nbsp;</p></td></tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="right"><p class="end-of-weekday-style">Â&nbsp;29Â&nbsp;</p></td>
      <td align="right"><a class="normal-day-style" onmousemove="window.status=&quot; &quot;" onmouseout="window.status=&quot; &quot;" title="" href="javascript:dateSelected=30;closeCalendar();doOtherFunctions();">Â&nbsp;30Â&nbsp;</a></td>
      <td align="right"><a class="normal-day-style" onmousemove="window.status=&quot; &quot;" onmouseout="window.status=&quot; &quot;" title="" href="javascript:dateSelected=31;closeCalendar();doOtherFunctions();">Â&nbsp;31Â&nbsp;</a></td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this (example assumes you are looking for div elements)

```
browser.divs(:how => 'what').last
```

The plural for most elements will return a collection of matching elements (e.g. add `s` or `es` to the element/tag name as would be appropriate.  div -> divs, address -> addresses)     And Ruby, great language that it is has a fast way to get the last element in collection via the `.last` method.

Comment: Thanks, I think that's it! At least I accessed `$browser.links(:class, "normal-day-style").last` without error.  At the time of my question I didn't recall which types of elements I'd faced this issue with, so didn't yet provide code samples.  In this case it was one of those popup calendars, with only eligible market days hotlinked--the idea was to select the farthest date available in the future, having already watir-clicked the NEXT arrow three months forward. (i.e. `id="spanRight" .click` x3)

Comment: Yes Ruby is awesome. Makes certain things a breeze that in other languages involved deep trickery.  Like and index of [-2] could get me the 2nd last member, [3..8] could easily fetch me the subset etc.

Answer (score 0):

tmp post.

The HTML in question is a popup calendar:

```
<table border="0" class="body-style">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td width="27" align="right"><b>Sun</b>
        </td>
        <td width="27" align="right"><b>Mon</b>
        </td>
        <td width="27" align="right"><b>Tue</b>
        </td>
        <td width="27" align="right"><b>Wed</b>
        </td>
        <td width="27" align="right"><b>Thu</b>
        </td>
        <td width="27" align="right"><b>Fri</b>
        </td>
        <td width="27" align="right"><b>Sat</b>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="right">
            <p class="end-of-weekday-style">Â&nbsp;1Â&nbsp;</p>
        </td>
        <td align="right">
            <p class="end-of-weekday-style">Â&nbsp;2Â&nbsp;</p>
        </td>
        <td align="right">
            <p class="end-of-weekday-style">Â&nbsp;3Â&nbsp;</p>
        </td>
        <td align="right">
            <p class="end-of-weekday-style">Â&nbsp;4Â&nbsp;</p>
        </td>
        <td align="right">
            <p class="end-of-weekday-style">Â&nbsp;5Â&nbsp;</p>
        </td>
        <td align="right">
            <p class="end-of-weekday-style">Â&nbsp;6Â&nbsp;</p>
        </td>
        <td align="right">
            <p class="end-of-weekday-style">Â&nbsp;7Â&nbsp;</p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="right">
            <p class="end-of-weekday-style">Â&nbsp;8Â&nbsp;</p>
        </td>
        <td align="right">
            <p class="end-of-weekday-style">Â&nbsp;9Â&nbsp;</p>
        </td>
        <td align="right">
            <p class="end-of-weekday-style">Â&nbsp;10Â&nbsp;</p>
        </td>
        <td align="right">
            <p class="end-of-weekday-style">Â&nbsp;11Â&nbsp;</p>
        </td>
        <td align="right">
            <p class="end-of-weekday-style">Â&nbsp;12Â&nbsp;</p>
        </td>
        <td align="right"><a class="current-day-style selected-day-style" onmousemove="window.status=&quot; &quot;" onmouseout="window.status=&quot; &quot;" title="" href="javascript:dateSelected=13;closeCalendar();doOtherFunctions();">Â&nbsp;13Â&nbsp;</a>
        </td>
        <td align="right">
            <p class="end-of-weekday-style">Â&nbsp;14Â&nbsp;</p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="right">
            <p class="end-of-weekday-style">Â&nbsp;15Â&nbsp;</p>
        </td>
        <td align="right"><a class="normal-day-style" onmousemove="window.status=&quot; &quot;" onmouseout="window.status=&quot; &quot;" title="" href="javascript:dateSelected=16;closeCalendar();doOtherFunctions();">Â&nbsp;16Â&nbsp;</a>
        </td>
        <td align="right"><a class="normal-day-style" onmousemove="window.status=&quot; &quot;" onmouseout="window.status=&quot; &quot;" title="" href="javascript:dateSelected=17;closeCalendar();doOtherFunctions();">Â&nbsp;17Â&nbsp;</a>
        </td>
        <td align="right"><a class="normal-day-style" onmousemove="window.status=&quot; &quot;" onmouseout="window.status=&quot; &quot;" title="" href="javascript:dateSelected=18;closeCalendar();doOtherFunctions();">Â&nbsp;18Â&nbsp;</a>
        </td>
        <td align="right"><a class="normal-day-style" onmousemove="window.status=&quot; &quot;" onmouseout="window.status=&quot; &quot;" title="" href="javascript:dateSelected=19;closeCalendar();doOtherFunctions();">Â&nbsp;19Â&nbsp;</a>
        </td>
        <td align="right"><a class="normal-day-style" onmousemove="window.status=&quot; &quot;" onmouseout="window.status=&quot; &quot;" title="" href="javascript:dateSelected=20;closeCalendar();doOtherFunctions();">Â&nbsp;20Â&nbsp;</a>
        </td>
        <td align="right">
            <p class="end-of-weekday-style">Â&nbsp;21Â&nbsp;</p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="right">
            <p class="end-of-weekday-style">Â&nbsp;22Â&nbsp;</p>
        </td>
        <td align="right"><a class="normal-day-style" onmousemove="window.status=&quot; &quot;" onmouseout="window.status=&quot; &quot;" title="" href="javascript:dateSelected=23;closeCalendar();doOtherFunctions();">Â&nbsp;23Â&nbsp;</a>
        </td>
        <td align="right"><a class="normal-day-style" onmousemove="window.status=&quot; &quot;" onmouseout="window.status=&quot; &quot;" title="" href="javascript:dateSelected=24;closeCalendar();doOtherFunctions();">Â&nbsp;24Â&nbsp;</a>
        </td>
        <td align="right"><a class="normal-day-style" onmousemove="window.status=&quot; &quot;" onmouseout="window.status=&quot; &quot;" title="" href="javascript:dateSelected=25;closeCalendar();doOtherFunctions();">Â&nbsp;25Â&nbsp;</a>
        </td>
        <td align="right"><a class="normal-day-style" onmousemove="window.status=&quot; &quot;" onmouseout="window.status=&quot; &quot;" title="" href="javascript:dateSelected=26;closeCalendar();doOtherFunctions();">Â&nbsp;26Â&nbsp;</a>
        </td>
        <td align="right"><a class="normal-day-style" onmousemove="window.status=&quot; &quot;" onmouseout="window.status=&quot; &quot;" title="" href="javascript:dateSelected=27;closeCalendar();doOtherFunctions();">Â&nbsp;27Â&nbsp;</a>
        </td>
        <td align="right">
            <p class="end-of-weekday-style">Â&nbsp;28Â&nbsp;</p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="right">
            <p class="end-of-weekday-style">Â&nbsp;29Â&nbsp;</p>
        </td>
        <td align="right"><a class="normal-day-style" onmousemove="window.status=&quot; &quot;" onmouseout="window.status=&quot; &quot;" title="" href="javascript:dateSelected=30;closeCalendar();doOtherFunctions();">Â&nbsp;30Â&nbsp;</a>
        </td>
        <td align="right"><a class="normal-day-style" onmousemove="window.status=&quot; &quot;" onmouseout="window.status=&quot; &quot;" title="" href="javascript:dateSelected=31;closeCalendar();doOtherFunctions();">Â&nbsp;31Â&nbsp;</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: since it's your question, you should be able to edit it to insert info like that.  but in the interest of speed I stuck the html above into your question and did a little formatting to make it readable.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time! It was a quick copy-paste from the src I didn't mean to keep here long anyway, to not pollute and since it's only one kind of sample among others within DOMs I've faced.  Your answer nailed it, hope it'll apply next time I'm stuck with generic `.element`s too.